# Working with git-svn: Proper workfllow

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I created a topic branch from the master; made some commits.

Then checked out the master; rebased it on the svn and merged the topic branch.

There were no commits on the master itself, so the merge was fast-forward.

Now, when I try to `svn dcommit` it gives me merge conflicts! wtf? Clearly there is a linear history on the master.

The workflow I follow is:

- create topic branches from the master,
- svn rebase the master,
- (generally) fast-forward merge the topic branches,
- git svn dcommit.

Is there a better way to deal with git-svn. I am not sure, I am using it rightly to create any distinctive advantage over using svn alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few readings regarding git svn workflows:

- [git svn workflow - feature branches and merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129688/git-svn-workflow-feature-branches-and-merge)
- http://blog.shinetech.com/?p=150
- http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial