# Will this git-svn workflow work?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm experimenting with `git-svn`, and am trying to come up with a relatively non error-prone workflow. I think the following should work, and is pretty simple, but I've seen [people using far more complicated workflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190431/is-git-svn-dcommit-after-merging-in-git-dangerous/190447#190447), so I want to see why.

1. `(master) $ git svn init <path>`
2. `(master) $ git svn fetch`
3. `(master) $ git svn rebase`
4. `(master) $ git checkout -b topic-branch`
5. `(topic-branch) $ # HACK HACK COMMIT HACK HACK HACK COMMIT HACK COMMIT`
6. `(topic-branch) $ git checkout master`
7. `(master) $ git merge topic-branch` -- this is a fast-forward merge, so no merge commit
8. `(master) $ git svn rebase`
9. `(master) $ # fix conflicts`
10. `(master) $ git svn dcommit`
11. `GOTO 4`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129688/git-svn-workflow-feature-branches-and-merge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's essentially what I do when working with Subversion repositories. The key to the simplicity of this is to keep the Git branches local and not try to map them to Subversion branches at all.

I just noticed that you linked directly to my answer in that other question. So perhaps I should explain more. :)

I sometimes do the conflict resolution in the topic branch if I expect some conflict work. Otherwise, if I don't expect many conflicts, I might merge to master first before doing the `git svn rebase`. It doesn't matter much.

The key point is that Git is so flexible that the *minimum* workflow is very simple. You've added a topic branch to that; I've added rebasing on the topic branch.

Answer (score 2):

From my brief experience I've made minor adjustments to your workflow and added comments:

1. `(master) $ git svn init <path>` (or `(master) git svn clone <url>`)
2. `(master) $ git svn fetch`
3. `(master) $ git svn rebase` (begin loop, resolve conflicts)
4. `(master) $ git checkout -B topic-branch` (*careful* before doing this)
5. `(topic-branch) ## HACK HACK COMMIT HACK COMMIT` (use 3rd party)
6. `(topic-branch) $ git checkout master`
7. `(master) $ git rebase topic-branch` (resolve conflicts)
8. `(master) $ git svn rebase` (resolve conflicts, if any)
9. `(master) $ git svn dcommit` (*careful* reading here)
10. GOTO 3 (or 4 if no need to rebase again)

I'm using **master** branch just for integration with SVN and doing all work on **topic-branch**, just like I believe you were. I hope this makes more sense, since I couldn't use your workflow the way it was even if it was basically what I wanted - evidently! :-)

More details on the adjustments that were made:

- Attention to capital **`-B`** on step 4, it will *reset* the topic-branch so it's always new from current SVN. without it the loop would break giving an error "branch already exists".
- Step 7 using `rebase` rather than `merge`. yes, it will probably be a fast-forward merge, but it's better safe than sorry. picture if something is done between steps 6 and 7.
- Loop to 3 instead of 4. Also, just to play on the safe side. Seems like using `svn rebase`  never is an abuse and since it's always done on master there's always branches as backup.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe if you while doing steps 5 never switch to master and do "git svn rebase". Else i would recommend doing a "git rebase master" between steps 5 and 6.