# git-svn trying to commit to wrong branch

Tags: git, git-svn

`git-svn dcommit` is trying to push to the wrong SVN branch. Here's what I did:

```
git checkout -b branch_a svn/branch_a  # git-svn clone prepended all remote SVN branches with svn/
git svn branch -m "a message" branch_b
git checkout -b branch_b svn/branch_b

<make some commits>

git svn dcommit
git checkout branch_a
git svn rebase
git checkout branch_b
git rebase branch_a
```

This is the "correct" branching/merging strategy I interpret from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129688/git-svn-workflow-feature-branches-and-merge) StackOverflow question.

Now I'm in a pickle. `git svn dcommit` from `branch_b` attempts to push to the SVN URL for `svn/branch_a`. This is confirmed by the output of `git svn info`. This is also not what I want or expect.

Interestingly, `git log --grep='^git-svn-id:' --first-parent -1` shows the correct SVN branch, the URL for `svn/branch_b`. I've read that this command is *supposed* to reveal where git-svn will dcommit to.

So:

1. What did I do wrong?
2. How can I fix it (i.e., push `branch_b` to `svn/branch_b`

Comment: Are those the exact checkout commands you used?  AFAIK you need -t in order to track a remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

Looking over your checkout commands, it seems you may not have instructed git svn to track the remote SVN branches correctly.  Try these commands:

```
git checkout -b branch_a -t svn/branch_a
git checkout -b branch_b -t svn/branch_b
```

and then verify the branch you are tracking after each with:

```
git svn info
```

Each branch should then be tracking the correct remote branch.